What type of input is required by a gate driver? The data sheet says 50 A
I'd like to drive a TI UC3708N gate driver from a handheld AWG square wave that varies between 0V and 2.5V.  According to the data sheet, anything above 2V should be treated as high:

However, I'm not sure how much current the TI UC3708N gate driver is expecting.  The data sheet is incomprehensible:

Clearly, it can't mean that the IC requires 50 A of input current to go high! Perhaps it's a typo and it means 50 mA? Even that seems too much.
I ask because I breadboarded a simple circuit, powered by 9V.  When I manually connect the IC's Input to 9V, I get a high output.  When I manually connect it to GND, I get a low output.  Yet when I connect it to the AWG, I get a flat line.
I have two hypotheses as to the cause:

The AWG's 2.5V is not enough to turn the IC on (despite the data sheet)
The AWG can't source enough current to turn the IC on

I can solve the first with a simple common emitter amplifier, and the second with a common collector follower.  But I'd first like to ask for help understanding what's actually required here.

FYI, the appropriate venue for such a question is the manufacturer's forums, a sales contact, or reporting a documentation error. There isn't much we can do here other than hint at what they possibly might've meant.

@TimWilliams I asked the question here because I wasn't sure if this was my misunderstanding.  The general rule, at least in software, is https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/ not to blame the machine.

See also https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11090814

Which part of the machine are we talking? Documentation is human-readable code of sorts; it's written by humans, and exactly as fallible as any software. In fact, worse: documentation doesn't ever need to work, users always have a chance to figure things out on their own. It's also safe to assume that "the machine" (corporations) are exactly as fallible as the people they're made of; especially today with rampant outsourcing and value-extraction by investors (not to get toooo political, but just to explain the general decline of infrastructure that's affected pretty much everything).

Yeah, I suspect that datasheet has typos, wouldn't be the first time.  Leakage currents,  and input currents of logic gates, are typically measured in pico or nano-amps, sometimes micro-amps.  I suggest reporting this to the manufacturer via their website.
The reason your circuit is not responding as you expect is because the logic high input threshold is tyically 2.8V, and could be as high as 3.6V.
So your first hypothesis is most likely correct.

Doesn't the data sheet say 2V is enough for high? Am I misreading it, or is that in error too?

I was referring to the Enable input.  Sorry, I can't post an image of it from my phone.

I have Enable tied directly to +9V.  Only the Input AWG is limited to 2.5V.

The data provided for logic inputs A & B is not complete.  Logic low max of 0.8V just means the threshold is always below 0.8V, but what is its min value that guarantees a LO?  Could be anything.  Same for Logic high, min= 2.0V, what is guaranteed hi level?  The data for input current gives a clue:  for HI is it given at 2.4V, not 2.0V.  I suspect the actual threshold in your case will be between 2.5V and 3.0V; the timing diagram on page 5 shows the input is 0 to 4.3V.  Thresholds might change with Vcc also, not sure.  Suggest try some experiments to find out.  Cheers.

Driving it with a stronger input solved it: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/717475/why-does-the-voltage-increase-when-i-connect-this-amplifier-to-a-gate-driver

@FabioBarone Vih,min and Vil,max are the guaranteed minimum and maximum values, not limits on the thresholds. The actual threshold is guaranteed to be above Vil,max and below Vih,min. This is how every logic input I've ever seen is specified.

@Hearth  I read that the opposite to you, it seems.  Input Low Level is specified as 0.8V max, with no mention of Min & Typ.  To me, that means the Input Low threshold is guaranteed to be below 0.8V, but could be as low as 0.0V.  So the threshold coubd be anywhere between 0V and 0.8V.  Input High Level threshold is specified as 2.0, which to me means it is guaranteed to be above 2.0V, and how high it could be is unspecified.  The OPs experience would seem to align with this interpretation.  So does the National Instruments website (like below).  Unless I am missing something?

Link to NI website:   https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000001Dn19CAC&l=en-US

This publication also agrees with my interpretation: //
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scla011/scla011.pdf

@FabioBarone If the input low level is specified as 0.8 V max, that means that 0.8 V is the maximum voltage you should present to the input when you want it to read low, i.e. the input threshold is guaranteed to be above 0.8 V. I don't see anything in that link that contradicts what I've just said. Perhaps this app note might be useful? Also perhaps section 2.8 of this document from Nexperia.

@FabioBarone The TI one doesn't appear to agree with your interpretation at all? Maybe I'm the one misunderstanding something?

Responding to: that means that 0.8 V is the maximum voltage you should present to the input when you want it to read low.  That's not how I read it.  It is the maximum threshold voltage for a zero input, meaning you have to drive it below that level, but how far below is not specified.  It has more to do with guaranteeing noise immunity than threshold level.  But maybe I'm wrong?

If my interpretation is incorrect, then that would mean the OPs chip is not operating to specifications.  Would not be the first time, I guess.

@FabioBarone Your interpretation wouldn't make for a very useful specification. You don't care what minimum voltage is guaranteed not to be interpreted as "low" (which is what your interpretation would imply), you care what maximum voltage is guaranteed to be interpreted as "low".

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This kind of nonsense is common as companies and their products are acquired and divested. Those parts were originally made by Unitrode. Below is a snippet from an archived Unitrode datasheet:

So the mu symbols got deleted due to some kind of font or similar issue. With mature products there is little pressure to fix the issue- existing users don’t care, most new users figure it out and years go by.. then the connection is forgotten.
